# How to increase the font size of colorbox scale in Gnuplot?

Tags: plot, graph, colors, gnuplot

[image]

I want to increase the font size of the colorbox scale (which has been marked as 0, 0.1,....1.0) in the attached image. Please answer how can I increase the font size of the scale.

I am expecting a larger font size of the scale but there is no documentation about it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Set the format for the axis tick labels using an "enhanced text" markup that changes the font size.  The command below will use the default format `%h` in the current font at three times the normal font size:

```
set cbtics format "{/*3.0 %h}"
splot x*y with pm3d
```

[image]